# Teamcity- run custom script with parameter

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, command-line-arguments

I've created a project in Teamcity that runs command line Custom script.
I want to add parameters to the script. something like:

```
./run.sh parameter
```

I want to be able to enter different parameter when running the build. as I understand  I can do it from the 'Run Custom Build' - but I didn't figure out how  exactly to enter a parameter for the custom script.

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration options for **Build parameters**, you can declare paramters that are `textbox`,`checkbox`  or `dropdown`. You can read more about them in the official documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Typed+Parameters)

This is an example for a textbox prompt

> [image: This is an example for a textbox prompt]

When you click on the Run button you will get this prompt

> [image]

You can use these to pass in values that change at runtime. Whenever you click on the **Run button**, you are going to be prompted for a value for these parameters before you can run the build. This is important, You can **not** run a build if you do not pass a value and click on enter.

Note that run button has 2 buttons partinioed side by side. the first button is labelled as `Run`, which is where you are prompted to **Only** change the value of variables that are dynamic. If you click on the 3 dots (ellipsis) `...` button, you can change **All** the variables before a custom build.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on ellipses on Run button.

[image]

And then click on prameters tab.

[image]

For more info, go through [Defining and Using Build Parameters in Build Configuration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration)

Comment: thanks, that explains how to run it, not how to configure it. and the documentation is not very clear, already checked it. anyway,  I've managed to do it and I will add the explanation. thanks.